# jQuery UI bug: dialog close changing radio buttons 

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

**ANOTHER EDIT**

The problem occurs when the dialog `close` is called. I'm pretty sure this is a bug, because there's a history of related bugs [1](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4589), [2](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/2804), [3](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6137), all marked as fixed. I get this problem with `modal` true or false, for both FF 12.0 and IE9; not tested anything else. I'm on 1.8.17. Anyone else seen this? I could try 1.8.20, but I'm losing the will to live.

---

I have two radio buttons in a modal pop-up. If button B is selected, lots of things happen - a div is displayed, the user fills in a form, some Ajax-y stuff goes on, a new jQuery UI tab is displayed and, eventually, a new modal is displayed, and I can see the two buttons again.

At the start of this process, button B is visibly checked. However, when the process completes, button B has magically become unchecked, and button A is checked. Some more info:

1. I don't programmatically change either button anywhere in the code, except at `onLoad`, when I select/check button A. I previously did this with `.attr`, and I'm now using `.prop` (see below). I'm on jQuery 1.7.
2. The html input tag for button A originally had a `checked` attribute
       on it.
3. If I use `.attr` for (1) above, then it doesn't matter whether the
       html does or doesn't include the `checked` attribute: I get the
       behaviour described above in both cases.
4. If I use `.prop` for (1) above, and take out the html `checked`
       attribute, then the behaviour changes. When button B is clicked and
       everything settles down, *neither* of the two radio buttons are
       selected.
5. I've got various other radio button pairs that do very similar things, and I've never seen this with them.
6. Checked on both FF and IE9
7. These are plain radio-input html buttons - I don't set up a jQuery UI group or anything special at all.
8. This only happens if I follow a complex sequence of steps. Normally, the buttons behave as expected.
9. If I add a change handler to the buttons, I can see that the handler is run whenever the buttons are manually checked, but it is *not* run when this problem occurs
10. There is no reloading of the page at any point; the onLoad routines aren't called when this problem occurs
11. The click handlers don't return false or prevent any default actions

Any idea what might be going on here, or how I can go about debugging this?

**EDIT**
A couple of extra points added above. Can't really add any code - there are hundreds of lines and I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: Could you add some markup/javascript code as well?

Comment: Without seeing it, people can only guess. Is the page reloading/refreshing without you knowing it?

Comment: During the complete UI interaction, I suspect the form is posted back to server/webpage is refreshed thus triggering window.onload handler

Comment: some ideas: first idea would be a triggered onLoad - but you ruled that out. second: one of your triggered actions fails silently, the process stops somewhere in the middle. third: not sure how jQuery handles the redisplay of your buttons. maybe the dom elements are rebuild and the checked information is missing

Comment: Thanks for the comments - had some progress. The form which the radio buttons are in is in a jQuery UI dialog. The  problem occurs on the call to the dialog `close`. When the dialog is closed, the value of these two buttons becomes undefined, but all the other buttons remain valid. I'll have a think about this for a bit and repost after changing the title.